# wp_enqueue_style action not working when file exists

Tags: wordpress

I am having a strange problem when trying to include a css file via wp_enqueue_scripts...

```
        function gn_enqueue_styles() {
        if ($_GET['gntpl']) {
            $gntpl = str_replace('.','_',$_GET['gntpl']);
            $handle = "gn_style_".$gntpl;
            $src = esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/site_css/$gntpl.css");
            $deps = array();
            $ver = false;
            $media = "all";
//            echo '<link rel="stylesheet" id="'.$handle.'" href="'.$src.'" type="text/css" media="all" />';
            wp_register_style( $handle, $src , $deps, $ver, $media );
            wp_enqueue_style( $handle );
        }
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gn_enqueue_styles', 1 );
```

When the path to the css file is incorrect (or file doesn't exist), I see the `<link ...>` statement in the pages source. The moment the path is correct, that whole `<link ...>` statement doesn't show up in the source and the css-file isn't loaded... I have verified the path several times and even entered the path directly, the behavior is confirmed - still I know there must be something wrong...

I am running out of ideas what I am doing wrong?! Side note, the same behavior happens when I use the commented out echo statement - it shows in source when path is incorrect, doesn't show when path is correct?!

Comment: You are not enqueueing the CSS in your code, you are just outputting the link... that is not the correct way to include CSS. See how to [enqueue CSS and js](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#enqueuing-scripts-and-styles). Enqueueing it correctly will fix the problem.

Comment: not sure where I am not enqueueing the file? please note that the echo was just for testing, the code does use the wp_enqueue_style as described in your link (at least I believe it does?!)

Comment: Sorry, you only refer to the link and echo’d line in your q so I thought that was where the problem was. I don't see an obvious problem with the rest of the code but its hard to know when variables are involved. Did you try to strip it back to basics first to see where exactly the problem is? Does it work if you hardcode the stylesheet name & handle, and remove the optional args to `wp_enqueue_style` that you don’t need here (deps, ver, media). Also why are you changing the priority to 1 in `add_action`?

Comment: it's o.k., I may have stated it a bit unclear - the echo I used just to see if something is wrong with my path or link. And yes, I have tried all this - it is really weird, the `<link ...>`only shows in the page source when the path points to a non-existing css - the moment the path correctly points to the css, the whole `<link ...>` disappears from the page source... I had changed the priority to one just to see if that would do anything (it didn't) and forgot to change it back...

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION/EXPLANATION:

Sometimes the right path is well hidden in the obvious... The effect was caused by the `autoptimize` plugin which combines all (existing) css files into one. So this was actually desired behavior and after disabling the plugin for test purposes showed that everything worked as it was supposed to...